# angular formControl value changes not working ([formControl].valueChanges) not working

Tags: angular, typescript

[formControl].valueChanges not working

.html

```html
<span>Test</span>
<input type="number" [formControl]="testForm">
```

.ts

```
testData: EventEmitter<any> =  new EventEmitter<any>();
testForm: FromControl;

constructor() {
  this.testForm = new FormControl();
}
    
this.testForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  const data: any = {
    value: this.testForm.value
  }
  this.testData.emit(data);
});
```

on change of the input i'm trying to emit the value, looks like something is wrong, testForm.valueChanges is not working, is there something I need to change on this ??

Comment: Where are you calling `this.testForm.valueChanges.subscribe`? In any lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the subscription into your constructor - example below.

```
testForm = new FormControl('');

constructor() {
    this.testForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });
};
```